# How to edit a user in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the ASP.NET Identity framework and I am trying to do some things. What I want to do is to edit the user who has already register and then update the user details to the database...
Previously, I use entity framework, and then its generated my controller view and model it self. But I want to update my user details and getting a list of users into a list..

How do I do these stuff? I have seen role methods..but I never understand,
How can I do? without using role..Because, I don't need administrator purposes. Only, I want to update my user details.

Comment: What you have done and where are you stuck can you post here ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a dbcontext object "context" and you also need to create a model class "UserEdit" and include those fields in it which you wants to edit.

```
private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
// To view the List of User 
 public ActionResult ListUsers ()
        {
            return View(context.Users.ToList());
        }

public ActionResult EditUser(string email)
        {
            ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser();
            appUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);
            UserEdit user = new UserEdit();
            user.Address = appUser.Address;
            user.FirstName = appUser.FirstName;
            user.LastName = appUser.LastName;
            user.EmailConfirmed = appUser.EmailConfirmed;
            user.Mobile = appUser.Mobile;
            user.City = appUser.City;


            return View(user);
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditUser(UserEdit model)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var currentUser = manager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
        currentUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        currentUser.LastName = model.LastName;
        currentUser.Mobile = model.Mobile;
        currentUser.Address = model.Address;
        currentUser.City = model.City;
        currentUser.EmailConfirmed = model.EmailConfirmed;
        await manager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
        var ctx = store.Context;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        TempData["msg"] = "Profile Changes Saved !";
        return RedirectToAction("ListUser");
    }
```

// for deleting a user

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var user = context.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(context.Users.Find(id));
        }


        public async Task<ActionResult> UserDeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            var result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                TempData["UserDeleted"] = "User Successfully Deleted";
                return RedirectToAction("ManageEditors");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["UserDeleted"] = "Error Deleting User";
                return RedirectToAction("ManageEditors");
            }
        }
```

Below is the View for ListUser:

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleApp.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListUsers";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>ManageEditors</h2>


            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        S.No.
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                     EmailConfirmed
                    </th>

                    <th>
                       FirstName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       LastName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Mobile
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @{ int sno = 1;
                   foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                         @(sno++)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailConfirmed)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { email=item.Email})
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new { id = item.Id })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
}
            </table>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

// below is my UserEdit Model

```
 public class UserEdit
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    }
```

//below is my IdentityModel.cs class which have ApplicationDbContext class

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace SampleApp.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        //Extra column added to auto generated Table by Code First approach (ASPNETUSERS) by Entity Framework
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: no need to call `ctx.SaveChanges()` after you have done `await manager.UpdateAsync(currentUser)`. UserManager already does this for you.

Comment: @Praveen Maurya - Could you please tell me, what you exactly mean "mod" in the code?

Comment: Yeah it is appUser.. i forgot to rename it while i was editing it

Comment: @Praveen Maurya - I was tried but i think model class also a bit of case

Comment: @Praveen Maurya - So maybe, the things you put here,...didn't work...Can you put a model class and dbcontext class also..

Comment: @PraveenMaurya - If you put, I am appreciate it...thanks

Comment: @Sungu Ruvin Please see the post , i have updated the content with UserEdit Model and also ApplicationDbContext class ..

Comment: @PraveenMaurya - do you use a key in the model class in order to generate a view

Comment: If you are using Scaffolding , then it will ask you for the key .. but i did it manually , So it was not required...

Comment: @PraveenMaurya - Thanks for everything, My problem solved...I appreciated you help...

Comment: I had an issue with `appUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);`, UserManager does not have `FindByEmail()`, I tried importing package but had issue. Ended up using: `var userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
            var appUser = userMgr.FindByEmail(email);`

Answer (score 5):

There is a class that comes with asp.net identity called **[UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199(v=vs.108).aspx)**
this class will help with the user information management you can first find a user using either

> - FindByIdAsync
> - FindByEmailAsync
> - FindByUserName

with the user object, you can then update it with new information for the user profile

and then use the method UpdateAsync to update the user information in the database.

when it comes to getting a list of users you can use the [**IdentityDbContext**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx) class to get the list of users from.

Comment: @Harshal Patil,Rahma Sammaron- Thanks for everything, My problem solved...I appreciate you help.. Thanks a lot.