# How to update my user account data on ASP.net MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am new to the asp.net MVC 5 identity framework andI am try to do update my details directly.
Straight forward, What I want to do is to update my user information to the database.
Previously, I changed my user details by using Migrations and I use entity framework in order to generate my controller, view and model it self.
However,  How do I update my user details. I have seen role methods..but I never understand, How can I do? without using role..Because, 
I want to update all of user information that I needed to do it in UserManageController...

Is it possible? in a different controller and getting values directly on generated user account? How to retrieve then?

Here is my Identity Models

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string userFname { get; set; }
        public string userLname { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string userContactNo { get; set; }
        public string commercialName { get; set; }
        public string commercialAddress { get; set; }
        public string commercialEmail { get; set; }
        public string userType { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Registeration model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User First Name")]
    public string userFname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Last Name")]
    public string userLname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Contact Number")]
    public string userContactNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Commercial Name")]
    public string commercialName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Commercial Address")]
    public string commercialAddress { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Commercial Email")]
    public string commercialEmail { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string userType { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362226/how-to-edit-a-user-in-asp-net-identity) looks similar to yours.

Comment: Please visit the below link , It may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362226/how-to-edit-a-user-in-asp-net-identity

Comment: Did you check my answer @HamunSunga ?? This is waht you are expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a user in ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362226/how-to-edit-a-user-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: @Basanta Matia - yeh, but I want direct access, not using a different model ...I am asking, can I get the model class which has auto generated itself in order to generate my edit? is it possible?

Comment: Yes @HamunSunga That's why I wrote in my example "Suppose your Update User method name is UpdateUserInfo". You can use your  RegisterViewModel itself. No problem at all.

Comment: @Basanta Matia..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I do this,

**UPDATED:** As he commented in my answer bellow, he want to update a list of users in the same method. So this will work.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUserInfo(List<RegisterViewModel> model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new 
                                  ApplicationDbContext());
    var appManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

    // here you can do a foreach loop and get the email and assign new datas
    foreach(var i in model)
     {
       var currentUser = appManager.FindByEmail(i.Email);

       // here you can assign the updated values
       currentUser.userFname = i.userFname;
       // and rest fields are goes here
       await appManager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
     }
    var ctx = userStore.Context;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    // now you can redirect to some other method or-else you can return 
    // to this view itself by returning the data

    return RedirectToAction("SomeActionMethod");
}
```

And yes, you should have the fields in your view and there will be a `@Html.BeginForm` and a `submit button` to post your data. Or-else you can post by `ajax` method

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to retrieve a list of users as well..Your answer perfectly works for me, but I want a list of users as well thats y......@Basanta Matia

Comment: Check my updated answer above, you can update list of user now...cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `ApplicationUser` class is part of your Entity Framework DBContext, you can retrieve and update a user like so, using Entity Framework;

```
var userId = "user id here"; // Set a user ID that you would like to retrieve

var dbContext = new YourDbContext(); // Your entity framework DbContext

// Retrieve a user from the database
var user = dbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().Find(userId);

// Update a property on your user
user.address = "New value";

// Save the new value to the database
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you need the userId of the current logged in user, use:

```
var userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Multiple users can be retrieved and updated like this:

```
var dbContext = new YourDbContext();

// Get all users
var users = dbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().ToList();

foreach (var user in users)
{
   user.address = "New value";
}

// Save the new value to the database
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Entity framework will automatically track the changes to each for when you save.

Comment: Can I get a list of users I mean not passing direct id

Comment: Thank you very much you also help me a lot..thanks for that...:)

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to give it a cheeky vote up :o)